# Firefox wont allow a HTTPS resource to be called on an http page

Tags: firefox, https

In chrome, I can call a secure URL (exampleB.com) from a INsecure page (exampleA.com); in firefox, they block it

Is this a bug, it seems HTTPS should be allowed from anywhere?

Resource being called is simply an IMG tag / GET request.

Comment: Sorry I read the opposite. I deleted my answer. Insert an https image on an http webpage should work. But if you try an ajax request from your http server to your https server it may be blocked, not because of https but because the protocol (https/http) si not the same, and you can't read an external answer without CORS headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with firefox itself. The CORS handling was backwards :)